# How ERC20 tokens control access to their functions?

Tags: ethereum

Here is my question (basically, I want to know if I am right or mistaken):

First of all, we have standard ERC20:

```
contract ERC20Interface
{
    function transfer(address _to, uint _value) public returns (bool success);
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) public returns (bool success);
    function approve(address _spender, uint _value) public returns (bool success);
.....
}
```

Then, in a CrowdSale, we have a token, derived from it:

```
contract ICO is Ownable {
...
MyToken public m_token;
...
function ICO() public {
m_token = new MyToken();
...
```

Then the crowdsale ends. The token with list of all people (addresses) that bought it becomes "free" of crowd sale contract:

```
function finish() onlyOwner public {
if(goalReached()) {
    m_token.transferOwnership(m_addrOwner);
```

My questions:
1. For this token to be traded on exchanges, I have to somehow provide these exchanges with token's address. Where should I get it? 
2. Am I correct? Is it how it supposed to work?

In other words, if a token is a separate contract, passed to ICO contract by address, I can see how exchanges can trade it after the end of crowd sale: they have that same address.
But I see a lot of crowdsales on Etherscan, that create contract internally (like in code snippets above). How do I make it "tradable" after the end of a crowd sale in this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most exchanges will only support your token if they see value in it. You'd have to contact the exchanges and they will evaluate if it's worth it to them based on the demand for your token. Even then, they will most likely ask for payment up front before listing.

For example, Bittrex has their submission process documented [here](https://support.bittrex.com/hc/en-us/articles/202583854-Submitting-a-Coin-to-Bittrex). They offer free listing once you pass their verification process (along with some non-free services). Other exchanges follow a similar process.

The contract address you're looking for that you'd have to provide is returned to your client when you deploy your token contract. If you somehow lose the address in your client, you can find it on etherscan.io by searching for the token name/symbol (assuming your token contract follows the ERC20 spec) or by transaction hash. You can also retrieve the address in code:

```
function getTokenAddress() constant returns (address) {
  return address(m_token);
}
```

Outside of an exchange, you can also do private transfers of tokens by simply adding the token contract address to a wallet like Mist or Parity and sending tokens between addresses.

Note that all of this is independent of the crowd sale. The crowd sale is a separate contract that is used to raise money and do the initial token distribution.

Comment: Thanks, but you missed the point. My question was: what if I create an ERC20 contract from within CrowdSale contract, as I do in a sample code in my question? What if there is no separate file with ERC20 contract? How do I get an address in this case? I mean, ERC20 contract is a member of Crowdsale contract. Crowdsale ended - how to use the ERC20 contract now? There are plenty of Crowdsales at etherscan that do it...

Comment: You can still find it by searching in etherscan.io by name/symbol. You can also get the address in code by using address(). Updated answer.

Comment: I agree about getting an address in code, but the problem is - in contracts like https://etherscan.io/address/0xb4925b5a1e7c00752f686f988926478ae0516115#code I do not see getting an address. It looks like they ran a crowdsale - and that's it. How do they pass the token to exchanges?                                      Adn I still can not understand the "You can still find it by searching in etherscan.io by name/symbol" part. The token was created inside CrowdSale contract, it is a class variable, why would it be on etherscan?

Comment: In this contract for example: https://etherscan.io/address/0x1e591bcf0b95b56f38b1700fde40598c4826f63e#code - it is simple enough to be sure that an address of a token is never returned...

Comment: Also :) sorry for so many questions. Say a token contract is already created and deployed. Then in a CrowdSale contract I issue: tokenReward = Token(0x98E2750d38b1D24Ba6C503E9853DB69e7Cf78fe4); That is not a new contract, right? It is a reference to an existing one?

Comment: It doesn't matter if a contract is created from your account or within another contract. Every contract created is visible on the blockchain. The token created inside CrowdSale is not a "class variable". It's just another contract that can be interacted with via any client tool. This is why security checks are very important.

Comment: BTW - Yet another way to find the contract address though Etherscan is to lookup the address of the first contract (ie, the links you posted in your comments above), and follow the internal transaction tabs. I'm too lazy to scan through all the Txs in the example you posted, so I created one that just creates a contract internally. https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x5ff3499eb311b34822f7f48f8244e9f8ebe9acf7. Click the TxHash address -> Click "Internal Transactions" tab. You'll see contract 0x6ea9e9ade36f6ba312ec0336732354ab2fcce797 (the internally created one).

Comment: And for your final question, you're correct. That is not a new contract, but is referencing an already deployed contract.

Comment: Thank you. It all is getting clear now :) One last question is about contracts like https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x5ff3499eb311b34822f7f48f8244e9f8ebe9acf7 - I see a crowdsale, with token CREATED in the same file, and they do not have any function to export an address of a cortex they created. There are many contracts like that one, and I don't think they search etherscan to find an address of their own contract... Is there something else I missed?